# Is this array possible in C? Is there any other way for it?

Tags: c, arrays, declaration

I declared an array in C of size 150X150X150. Upon compiling the program to get an array of same size,the compiler gave no errors or warnings. but when I tried running it, the program stops responding.

```
void main(){
 int i,j,k;
 char giv[150][150][50],tar[150][150][50];
 for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
 {
  for(j=0;j<150;j++)
  {
   for(k=0;k<50;k++)
    cin>>giv[i][j][k];
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any way that I can create an array of 150*150*150 without causing a run time error? 
EDIT: I know multidimensional arrays work. This is not a compilation error. Its a run time error, whose cause was I am not able to pinpoint.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking but if you're asking whether multi-dimensional arrays are possible, the answer is yes for all C, C++ and Java.

Comment: Tried executing what? You can't execute an array.

Comment: Maybe post a small sample on how you tried to use your array. You're probably having an infinite loop if it stops "responding".

Comment: If they are locally declared arrays you might have broken the stack. Use `malloc()` to allocate dynamic memory.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As a clarification to what @WeatherVane said: 150 * 150 * 50 = 1 125 000 bytes > 1MB is probably too much memory to hold on the stack. Using dynamically allocated memory should fix this.

Comment: @zenith two such arrays is > 2 MBytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could allocate the arrays on the heap:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc()/calloc() */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */

...

char (*pgiv)[150][150][50] = malloc(sizeof *giv);
char (*ptar)[150][150][50] = malloc(sizeof *tar);
```

If you want to have the arrays' elements initialised to all `0`s on allocation use `calloc()` as follows:

```
char (*pgiv)[150][150][50] = calloc(1, sizeof *giv); 
char (*ptar)[150][150][50] = calloc(1, sizeof *tar);
```

Also test wether the allocation succeed or not:

```
if (NULL == pgiv)
  perror("malloc() failed");
if (NULL == ptar)
  perror("malloc() failed");
```

Address an element by doing for example:

```
(*pgiv)[0][1][2] = 123;
```

Note that `pgiv` and `ptar` are actually pointers (to an array). That's why they need to be dereferenced (using the dereference operator `*`) before being used like an array.

Answer (score 7):

You just declared two arrays on the stack.

Each array has size: 150 * 150 * 50 bytes, or about 1.1MB.
So you are asking for 2.2MB from the stack.

Typical stack size is about 1 or 2MB.

**So I expect you're getting a StackOverflow Exception.**
*(kinda appropriate for this site)*

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is with the limit of the stack memory.

In C++ you could use for example standard container `std::vector`.

In C you could allocate these arrays yourself dynamically.

The simplest way is either to declare these arrays globally that is outside any function or specify keyword `static` that the arrays had static storage duration. For example

```
static char giv[150][150][50],tar[150][150][50];
```

As for other languages then for example Java and C# allocate arrays in the managed heap. It keeps in the stack only a reference to the array.

Comment: The question was about C.

Comment: But `std::vector` is C++, not C

Comment: @zenith Is it a big problem? :)

Comment: Quoting the question: "*is c++ or java capable of this*"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Now it's better :)

Comment: But... surely better to use the language of choice correctly to suit the task, rather than change the language?

Comment: @Weather Vane  It is difficult to say. Maybe it is time to look at other languages.:)

Comment: I downvoted you for suggesting that making it static was the simplest way. It may require the least typing but the semantic implications are not simple at all.

Comment: @Puppy "Semantic implications are not simple at all"? It is something new. But maybe indeed it is not simple for you.

Comment: Static not thread safe(

Comment: @Martin James Where was there said about threads?! I wrote that it is the simplest way but what way will be selected is the choice of the author of the topic.